# Postgres timestamp equality

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a table with just two columns:

```
ts::timestamptz (unique),
values::jsonb
```

I need to find a row with specific ts, but no matter how I cast and convert things around, it just does not work. E.g.

```
select t.ts::timestamp from table t limit 1   ... returns 2020-03-16 12:46:02
```

this query

```
to_timestamp('2020-03-16 12:46:02','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  ... returns  2020-03-16 12:46:02
```

but query

```
select * from table t where t.ts::timestamp = to_timestamp('2020-03-16 12:46:02','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

returns nothing. Now apparently I'm doing a rookie mistake somewhere, but I just can't see it.

Comment: I don't believe that your queries return what you say they do. Where is the time zone?

Comment: My table and columns are named differently, I tried to simplify it a bit to make it more descriptive, but the very core of my issue is as I described

Comment: A `timestamp` has a microsecond precision. Your stored value is probably something. like `2020-03-16 12:46:02.123456` rather than `2020-03-16 12:46:02.00000`

Comment: Ok, that is possible. But the nature of the question is...I pulled some data from postgres to python and now I need to identify unique record by timestamp. There are many hints on the web how to select records by date, or between intervals. I could not find anything to use actual timestamp equality

Comment: Why don't you [edit] your question and describe its nature? The way you show the timestamps is not how they look in PostgreSQL. So you had better describe how you go about displaying the timestamps. Something might mangle them on the way.